# Android get Text from Web

Tags: java, android, text, web, get

I have problem with getting text from webpage for example [tested page](http://ps-bred02.eu/ip.php) I'm using this code

```
private String getTextFromWWW(String URLin) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(URLin);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String text = in.readLine();            
        in.close();

        return text;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "Error > " + e.getMessage();

    }
}
```

I added premission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`
When i start this script I always get just "Error > null" ... I used this function in  normal Java app and it worked normally.

Comment: can you print complete stacktrace of exception

Comment: There is it http://dl.ps-bred02.eu/tr.png

Comment: You probably aren't getting a full stacktrace if you're handling the exception like that. Add a log statement to every other line to determine where the code is breaking.

Comment: And how can i add a log statement ??